# Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([169])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

when I am running the GAN code in PyTorch it is working fine for 64*64 images but it is giving the following error when the image size is 256*256:

```
ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([169])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

Pneumonia heart disease dataset I have used.

code

## Training the DCGANs

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss() # We create a criterion object that will measure the error between the prediction and the target.
optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr = 0.0002, betas = (0.5, 0.999)) # We create the optimizer object of the discriminator.
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr = 0.0002, betas = (0.5, 0.999)) # We create the optimizer object of the generator.

for epoch in range(100): # We iterate over 25--100 epochs.

    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0): # We iterate over the images of the dataset.
        
        # 1st Step: Updating the weights of the neural network of the discriminator

        netD.zero_grad() # We initialize to 0 the gradients of the discriminator with respect to  the weights.
        
        # Training the discriminator with a real image of the dataset
        real, _ = data # We get a real image of the dataset which will be used to train the discriminator.
        input = Variable(real) # We wrap it in a variable.
        target = Variable(torch.ones(input.size()[0])) # We get the target.
        output = netD(input) # We forward propagate this real image into the neural network of the discriminator to get the prediction (a value between 0 and 1).
        errD_real = criterion(output, target) # We compute the loss between the predictions (output) and the target (equal to 1).
        print(input.size(),target.size())
        # Training the discriminator with a fake image generated by the generator
        noise = Variable(torch.randn(input.size()[0], 100, 1, 1)) # We make a random input vector (noise) of the generator.
        fake = netG(noise) # We forward propagate this random input vector into the neural network of the generator to get some fake generated images.
        target = Variable(torch.zeros(input.size()[0])) # We get the target.
        output = netD(fake.detach()) # We forward propagate the fake generated images into the neural network of the discriminator to get the prediction (a value between 0 and 1).
        errD_fake = criterion(output, target) # We compute the loss between the prediction (output) and the target (equal to 0).

        # Backpropagating the total error
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake # We compute the total error of the discriminator.
        errD.backward() # We backpropagate the loss error by computing the gradients of the total error with respect to the weights of the discriminator.
        optimizerD.step() # We apply the optimizer to update the weights according to how much they are responsible for the loss error of the discriminator.

        # 2nd Step: Updating the weights of the neural network of the generator

        netG.zero_grad() # We initialize to 0 the gradients of the generator with respect to the weights.
        target = Variable(torch.ones(input.size()[0])) # We get the target.
        output = netD(fake) # We forward propagate the fake generated images into the neural network of the discriminator to get the prediction (a value between 0 and 1).
        errG = criterion(output, target) # We compute the loss between the prediction (output between 0 and 1) and the target (equal to 1).
        errG.backward() # We backpropagate the loss error by computing the gradients of the total error with respect to the weights of the generator.
        optimizerG.step() # We apply the optimizer to update the weights according to how much they are responsible for the loss error of the generator.
        
        # 3rd Step: Printing the losses and saving the real images and the generated images of the minibatch every 100 steps

        print('[%d %d][%d %d] Loss_D: %.4f Loss_G: %.4f' % (epoch, 100, i, len(dataloader), errD.data, errG.data)) # We print les losses of the discriminator (Loss_D) and the generator (Loss_G).
        if i % 100 == 0: # Every 100 steps:
            vutils.save_image(real, '%s/real_samples.png' % "/content/result", normalize = True) # We save the real images of the minibatch.
            fake = netG(noise) # We get our fake generated images.
            vutils.save_image(fake.data, '%s/fake_samples_epoch_%03d.png' % ("./result", epoch), normalize = True) # We also save the fake generated images of the minibatch.
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: updated please have a look

Comment: What you updated isn't really relevant for the error .. rather the model description and dataloaders are important.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15Nwh8wEbKY--s7Ue5Xd6qJrx3RDLCJjo?usp=sharing
complete code will you plz look into it